# How do I build an expression with a certain signature?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I'm trying to call a method with a parameter of type `Expression<Func<T, string>>` but the expression tree that I build doesn't allow me to call the method. Here's a short but complete program demonstrating the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get { return ""; } }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo<Test>();
    }

    static void Foo<T>()
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "Name");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);
        Bar<T>(lambda);
    }

    static void Bar<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> expression) {}
}
```

Error:

```
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from
'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression' to 
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, string>>'
```

How can I pass my expression tree to the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually already building an expression tree which has the right type at *execution* time (if you just don't try to call the method, and print out the type of the object that the value of `lambda` refers to). However, the compile-time type of `lambda` is just `LambdaExpression`, not `Expression<Func<T, string>>`. That's because you're using a non-generic overload of `Expression.Lambda` which is designed to be used when you *don't* know the desired expression tree type at compile-time. That does the right thing at execution time, but doesn't allow you to use it in a strongly-typed way.

Fortunately, you *do* know the type of the expression tree you want to produce, so you just need to specify that in a call to a generic overload of `Expression.Lambda`:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(property, parameter);
```

That will throw an exception at execution time if the expression tree you've built up doesn't have the right type, e.g. if the `Value1` property is of the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda was being built incorrectly.

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "Value1");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(property, new[] { parameter });
```